I am getting selenium error in Python, how can I solve this?
I created a Python file called ahmet.py in Visual Studio Code, but I get this error.;
ahmet.py : The term 'ahmet.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and t
ry again.
At line:1 char:1

ahmet.py

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ahmet.py:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




help me
How can I solve this error?
